# I get same error with my DataMapper models no matter how i'm building them

Tags: ruby, datamapper

Whatever columns/types/relations i'm using within my DataMapper models i'm always get same fatal error:

```
undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass
```

a sample model:

```
class Book
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
end
```

Even with this trivial model i get that weird error.

Latest datamapper, reinstalled to be sure it is no broken somehow.
Ruby 1.9.3
Mysql 5

Sequel works just well on same environment.

Comment: What line of code gives you the error?

Comment: Sergio, the line where i'm trying to create a new item, i.e. `Book.create :name => 'blah'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you call `DataMapper.finalize` after defining your models?

try:

```
class Book
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
end

DataMapper.finalize # this is required on any scenario
```

Official docs:
http://datamapper.org/getting-started.html

See **Finalize Models** at the bottom

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, will try to find official docs, however this is a common DataMapper practice to `finalize` models after defining them.

Comment: Worked! Thank You. Wondering how could i miss it